# What is this error in RStudio: "breakpoints will be activated when the file or function is finished executing"?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to set a break point inside a function from a package I wrote. I am unsuccessful when clicking next to the line number in Rstudio, the error message looks like:

[image]

I am not executing anything. Reloading the package did not help either. What is this error and what can I do about it?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Code should still run.

Comment: Hi, to clarify, when this 'warning' occurs a open red circle appears next to the line number. The issue here, and why I am saying it is an error, is that I don't see a red circle (i.e. clicking does not seem to have done anything except to throw the warning).

Comment: Five years on and this is still an ongoing problem!  This very regularly happens to me.  The only way to clear it is to restart R which can be very annoying when you are using Debug to isolate a problem with code.  That it is a warning not an error is irrelevant.  The debug function doesn't work.  Definitely a Rstudio Bug

Answer (score 9):

Check out this [documentation from RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534337-Breakpoint-Troubleshooting) that explains what to do.

Basically, make sure you save your R file, then click the Source button on the toolbar:
[image]

Your breakpoint should then turn from a hollow red circle to a full one.

Comment: Nope. I have the same problem. Note that he is writing a R package, so he should **NOT** source the file.

When writing R packages, I use devtools:load_all().  RStudio can set breakpoints inside the package code and stop when we call a function. But everytime you execute a R package function and force it to stop using the Quit button in RStudio console, the debugger will no longer be able to set breakpoints. Its a RStudio bug.

Answer (score -5):

Usually running `rm(list=ls())` will do the job.

Comment: Please use some language decoration for future posts. E.g. upper case at the start of a sentence and punctuation at the end. StackOverflow does not require perfect English (or I myself would be pretty lost), but that kind of care when typing can be expected.

Comment: That removes all user-created objects in the environment. It doesn't restart the R session or run the script, which is what this question is about. It is, however, [a good way to ruin someone's day](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/) if that's your M.O.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with solving the OA problem, but might create new problems instead.